# Notification comes too frequent instead of once a day

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

I am trying to build an app which sends a notification same time everyday (at noon). however, it comes like every two hours. Is there something I'm doing wrong?
This is the snippet of my code that sets the alarm timing.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

    findViewsById();

    setDateTimeField();

    today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Intent myIntent=new Intent(Main.this, MyReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this,0,myIntent,0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,today.getTimeInMillis(),24*60*60*1000,pendingIntent);
```

please any help is appreciated. The code works but it comes too frequently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out,
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

```
// Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);

// With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
// constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: hey so I changed it but when I click the notification, it does not show the notification page anymore?? :/